# docker - creating and starting container, differences between API and CLI

Tags: docker

I want to create a (named) container through the API without starting it (otherwise I would have to manually stop it immediately, not very clean), and use systemd to manage it as a service, but I'm a bit confused between the CLI and the API involved...

In the API, some parameters for the container are given at the "start" phase and not at the creation, like volume-from, ports bindings, network mode, etc. while in the CLI it can only be given with the run command and not with the start.

So, how can I create a container with the API and then start it with the cli and still pass these parameters ?

Thanks

Comment: show your codes, please

Comment: I don't have a source yet, I'm looking in the documentation how to achieve my goal... Create a container through the API [https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.12/#21-containers]: no option "volume-from" (present in the "start" call). start command through the CLI [https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#start]: no "volume-from" option (present in the "run" command)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the container, you'll define which image you want to use and the command you want it to execute:

```
POST /containers/create HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
     "Image":"busybox",
     "Cmd": "ls"
}
```

Then in starting the container, you CAN override some of the container's configuration (such as the **Cmd**), but otherwise, you will simply tell it to run with your volume or port bindings:

```
POST /containers/(id)/start HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
     "Binds":["/tmp:/tmp"],
     "PortBindings":{ "22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "11022" }] }
}
```

The CLI, specifically, **docker run** creates, then starts the container in a single step.

Simplified JSON blocks taken from the API documentation at https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.14

Comment: @Robert Let us know if this helped answer your question!